# How to set and get a private variable in javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using the radioButton in javaFX  to set a parameter.

```
public class SelectCOM extends Application {
private int comNum ;

public int getComNum() {
    return comNum;
}

public void setComNum() {
    launch();
}
    @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    //......

    //OK BUTTON
     btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            String str = tg.getSelectedToggle().toString();
            int begin = str.indexOf("COM");
            str = str.substring(begin+3, str.length()-1);
            comNum = Integer.parseInt(str);
            System.out.println(comNum);
            primaryStage.close();
        }
    });
}
```

When I call `setComNum`, the variable `comNum` is changed to the number I want. But `getComNum` just return 0.
Here is my calling method:

```
    SelectCOM selectCOM = new SelectCOM();
    selectCOM.setComNum();//After clicking the OK BUTTON about 3s, a 0 printed.
    int com = selectCOM.getComNum();
    System.out.println(com);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *static* `launch()` method in `Application` creates a new instance of your `Application` subclass, starts the JavaFX toolkit, and invokes `start()` on the instance it created. (The call to `start()` is made on the FX Application Thread.)

So you are setting the `comNum` value on the field in the instance created by the call to `launch()`, but you are calling `getComNum()` on the instance you created yourself (i.e. on a different object); hence you don't get the correct value.

Note also the `launch()` method, and consequently your `setComNum()` method, will not complete until the JavaFX Platform exits (by default this is when the user closes the last window).